# Graph equation code fix needed!

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate, code-review

I am trying to graph this image[image: yield effort curve]

using this line of code

```
Manipulate[ (sol = 
   NDSolve[{y[t] == h[t]*(Ke^(-h[t]/r)), y[0] == 0.001}, 
    y[t], {t, 0, 1000}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 10}]), {{r, 0.01}, 0, 0.05}, {{Ke, 5}, 0, 10}]
```

But my code isn't working.  Can you tell me what's wrong?  This is the equation that is supposed to model the graph

$$y=hKe^{-\frac{h}{r}}$$

Comment: What is `h[t]` and `x[t]`? and it's not a differential equation.

Comment: that's the harvesting rate with respect to time. x[t] is supposed to be y[t]

Comment: oh sorry I mean just equation

Comment: Is there any expression for `h[t]`?

Comment: Now that I think about it, if it's just a regular equation there is no need for it to be dependent on time so we can just remove the "of t" altogether

Comment: There are quite a few issues. 1. It's not a DE then no need to use `NDSolve`. 2. `h[t]` is unknow. 3. use `Exp` not `e^`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the equation at the end. Just plot it:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[h*k*Exp[-h/r], {h, 1, 1000}, PlotRange -> All],
 {{k, 50}, 10, 100},
 {{r, 50}, 10, 100}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]